# Not getting any useful log output from Rails3 app on DreamHost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, dreamhost

I'm trying to deploy an extremely simple Rails application on my shared DreamHost account, and am stuck. The log output doesn't seem to tell me what is wrong.

When I access any resource of the app in the browser, it returns the standard 404 error page (public/404.html). All that the log/production.log file says:

```
Started GET "/" for 198.144.202.78 at Wed Aug 15 14:34:58 -0700 2012 Processing by HomeController#index as HTML   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (5.3ms)


Started GET "/internal_error.html" for 198.144.202.78 at Wed Aug 15 14:34:58 -0700 2012

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/internal_error.html"):
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:513:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:205:in `start_request_handler'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:170:in `send'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:170:in `handle_spawn_application'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:165:in `handle_spawn_application'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:128:in `start'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `spawn_rack_application'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `spawn_rack_application'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `synchronize'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  /dh/passenger/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99
```

As I understand, the only error being reported is that it cannot find the "internal_error.html" page to redirect to. (Although I did create one at public/internal_error.html - that didn't help). In any case, it doesn't tell me what error it encountered (which is what I'm looking for). I have set config.log_level = :debug in config/environments/production.rb.

The apache error log (~/logs/MY_DOMAIN/http/error.log) only says:

```
[Wed Aug 15 14:34:58 2012] [error] [client 198.144.202.78] Premature end of script headers:
```

Anyway, here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'json'
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
#  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'ruby-debug'
gem "rake", "0.8.7"
#gem "rmagick"
# gem "rmagick", ">= 1.15", :require => 'RMagick'
gem "rmagick", "1.15.14", :require => 'RMagick'
gem "carrierwave"
gem "therubyracer"
```

Some details on the environment:

rails - using ~/.gems/bin/rails version 3.2.8
ruby - using /usr/bin/ruby as far as I can tell version 1.8.7
rake - using /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin//rake version 0.8.7

I was able to successfully run bundle and rake db:migrate (after jumping through lots of hoops).

Comment: It looks like you have no defined route for the path you are asking for

   No route matches [GET]

Comment: I'm only requesting the root of the webapp (i.e. mydomain.com/). If I run rake routes, a root route is defined: `root / home#index`. And there is a file at `app/views/home/index.html.erb`. Also, this happens with _every_ path I request, not just /.

Comment: I haven't seen this before `Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (5.3ms)  It looks like you have something wrong in index.html.erb. Try reducing it to the minimum expression.

Comment: app/views/home/index.html.erb contains only two lines of HTML: <h1>Home#index</h1>
<p>Hello Antun</p>